# symfony production mod not working whit debug=false

Tags: symfony

I create an application in symfony and run it under prod env. but a bundle has 500 Internal error.
I clear cache but problem was not solved.

Finally I change $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); in app.php and problem solved. 
but When application has an error it shows full error with debug!!!
How can I solve this probleme?dev env has no error

Comment: You did something wrong. I think that you cleared your cache without parameter `--env=prod`

Comment: I deleted it from app directory:)

Comment: Please share the content of your `app/logs/prod.log` after try to browse your application in production with debug to false (`$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);`)